# How do you rate/review an extension for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to rate (i.e. choose a star out of 5) and possibly leave a review for an extension in VS Code, but can't seem to find out how (either through the website of the extension in the marketplace, or the IDE itself)... any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to View -> Extensions:

[image]

Click on the desired extension on the left-hand side menu:

[image]

Click on the Stars and you'll be taken to the extension's page.

[image]

You can now rate/write a review (as long as you are logged in)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When it takes you to marketplace, make sure to login and then you can write a review.